# Writing the symmetry group of a cube without using direct products

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-isomorphism, symmetry, direct-product

The symmetry group of a cube $G$ is commonly cited as being $G \cong S_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. However, the definition of an internal direct product (i.e see this link https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Internal_direct_product) demands that the elements of $S_4$ i.e our rotations commute with the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ i.e our reflection which isn't true. What should I do? Is there some way to get around this?

Comment: The rotations **do** commute with the central reflection $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: What is wrong with $O_h$?

Comment: Hi Oscar - what do you mean by $O_h$? I don't think I've seen that notaiton before

Comment: And what do you mean by the central reflection for a cube? I understand what you mean by that on a plane, but in $3$-D can you please clarify?

Comment: what about the Dynkin graph  o---o-4-o  ?